# Sorting of array based by an override lookup list

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array where I need to sort as usual with certain words to be placed at the end (override precedence) with a place_last_lookup array.

```
input_place_last_lookup = ["not","in"];
input_array = [ "good", "in", "all", "are", "not", "programmers", "the", "world"]
input_array.sort(function(){/*override*/})
expected_output = ["all", "are", "good", "programmers", "the", "world", "not", "in"]
```

where not and in will be placed at the end, since these words are in lookup array.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first compare whether the compared strings are in the lookup table, and only when that is a tie, use the normal comparison:

```js
let always_last = ["not","in"];
let array = [ "good", "in", "all", "are", "not", "programmers", "the", "world"]
array.sort((a, b) => always_last.includes(a) - always_last.includes(b) 
                  || a.localeCompare(b));
console.log(array);
```

Notes:

- The strings that match with the lookup list will *also* be sorted among themselves, so this solution will put "in" before "not" at the end of the output.
- if you have many elements in the lookup array, then you should consider storing those values in a Set (or as keys in a plain object). This because `Array#includes` has a linear time complexity, while `Set#has` has a constant time complexity (amortised).

If the order of the matches with the lookup array should be according to their order in the lookup array, then use `indexOf` instead of `includes`:

```js
let always_last = ["not","in"];
let array = [ "good", "in", "all", "are", "not", "programmers", "the", "world"]
array.sort((a, b) => always_last.indexOf(a) - always_last.indexOf(b) 
                  || a.localeCompare(b));
console.log(array);
```

#### Placing items always first

If some items need to be sorted first *and* some others last, then just use a similar expression, but *negated* (i.e. swap the role of `a` and `b`):

```js
let always_first = ["programmers"];
let always_last = ["not","in"];

let array = [ "good", "in", "all", "are", "not", "programmers", "the", "world"]
array.sort((a, b) => always_last.includes(a) - always_last.includes(b)
                   || always_first.includes(b) - always_first.includes(a) 
                   || a.localeCompare(b));
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Trincot, Could you let me know how do I place some items at first and some at last with **both** *input_place_first_lookup* as well as *input_place_last_lookup* using a Set#has as my list is quite long

Comment: Is it possible to have both input_place_**last**_lookup = ["not","in"]; and input_place_*first*_lookup = ["programmers"]; in a single run.

Comment: Added a section of putting strings first instead of last.